# rpy2 and Jupyter Notebook. How to render R results inline in cell mode?

Tags: python, r, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Line mode (`%R`) works fine that is computation result (eg `%R y <- 1; y`) are rendered below the cell of Jupyter notebook.

But cell mode (`%%R`) returns results in the IPython terminal (the Windows terminal like that pops while starting Ipython).

[Here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/extensions/rmagic.html) the IPython documentation reads:

> In cell mode, this will run a block of R code. The resulting value is printed if it would printed be when evaluating the same code within a standard R REPL.
>
> Nothing is returned to python by default in cell mode

How can I change those defaults parameters so that `%%R` renders inline?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the R magic. See if it's been reported in the [rpy2 issues](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues). Most of the people working on these things use Linux or Mac, so it may be that a problem on Windows has gone unnoticed.

Comment: Thank you for your input Thomas. I went through bitbucket. I couldn't find identical problems. But following what I read, this also may be due to Windows as you suggested. Another thing I noticed running rpy2 tests is that it was "built agains" R version: 3-2.2--69059" (output from the test) while I am using R (x64) 3.2.3.

Comment: I don't think that the minor difference in the R version should affect this, though it's not impossible. Make sure that you're using the current version of the R magic from rpy2 (i.e. doing `%load_ext rpy2.ipython`), not the older version that was included with IPython. If you are, I think you can open an issue on rpy2 about it.